# Range index object has no attribute 'end'

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

Iam doing Time series forecasting by SARIMAX model. Code which I ran for the programming was

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
fit1 = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX( train_original.Count, order=(2, 1, 4),seasonal_order=(0,1,1,7)).fit()
```

[image: train_original_Count data]
How I clear the error, kindly help, Thanks

Comment: Range Index object has no attribute end - error

Comment: Please [do not post images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of your data. You can include [code that creates a dataframe or the output of `print(df)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) (or of a few rows and columns that allow to reproduce the example)

Answer (score 0):

Updating pandas version to 1.1.3 worked for me.
Please try :

pip uninstall pandas -y

pip install pandas==1.1.3